# How do I perform an FADC?

Tags: super-street-fighter-iv

How do I perform an FADC for any character in SSF4: AE 2012?

I have tried various way but I'm not able to do it.

I know there are only some moves which can be FADC-able but I am not able to do any of it. I have tried first Ryu's DP(with all three punch buttons which uses a meter) and then press focus to cancel it but I'm not able to cancel it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you can only FADC Ryu's DP if it hits something or is blocked. So put a dummy in front of you and set it to autoblock, then try.

To FADC, you want to do:

1. The Shoruken motion, then
2. Immediately Focus (MP+MK), then
3. Dash (Left, Left or Right, Right).

The timing is tough at first but gets easier with practice. You should use Ryu's MP Shoryuken, as that's his most common anti-air, or the EX version, as it can be FADC'ed on the second hit as well.

Comment: ok i will try this and thx a lot for the answer i am up voting this   for now and if i am able to do this then i will accept it .. and for all moves is this same ??

Comment: thx a lot again for guiding it .. ya i m not able to do it everytime  right now but now i know i need to practice but i will b e able to do it .. thx again

Answer (score 2):

To execute a FADC (focus attack dash cancel) you first need to focus attack out of a move. Please look at [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/118640/fadc-what-is-it-excactly-and-how-does-it-work) which moves can be canceled.

Bascially you execute a move and after you hit and you are still on the ground you press MP and MK to cancel the move. Try it first with Hadoken, as this is usually easier to execute. So just train Hadoken...FA. If you succeed you will glow yellow and you will cancel the animation of your previous move and make a focus attack.

Once you feel comfortable with the timing, then hold the FA after the Hadoken and press forward twice, as if you want to dash. Then release MP+MK. You can of course also dash backwards.

Go in training mode and display your input. If you tend to press something like MP before MP+MK then you will not FADC. Try to vary the timing. Usually you have to FA after the hit, but it is not enough time to "hit confirm", just assume that you will hit and use the timing from your muscle memory.

In the end it just boils down to training and crisp execution.

FYI: You cannot FADC Ryu's HP Shoryuken.